# Using MDI with TabControl and using instances of the same form that work independently

Tags: c#, forms, tabcontrol, mdi

I'm trying to create an application that uses MDI with TabControl. When frmMain creates a new frmCharacter if there is more than one it adds them to a TabControl.

The problem is that changes made to a, for example a ComboBox, Control in one form changes the same Control in the other duplicate forms.

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Thank you.

**frmMain**

```
namespace DarkHeresyCC
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void newCharacterToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Character objCharacter = new Character();

            frmCharacter frmChar = new frmCharacter(objCharacter);
            frmChar.MdiParent = this;
            frmChar.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            frmChar.Show();
        }
        private void frmMain_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // If there are no child forms, hide the tab control.
            if (this.ActiveMdiChild == null)
                tabMain.Visible = false;
            else
            {
                this.ActiveMdiChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

                // If this is a new child form and does not have a tab page, create one.
                if (this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag == null)
                {
                    // Add a tab page.
                    TabPage tp = new TabPage(this.ActiveMdiChild.Text);
                    tp.Tag = this.ActiveMdiChild;
                    tp.Parent = tabMain;

                    //if (this.ActiveMdiChild.GetType() == typeof(frmCareer))
                    //{
                    //    tp.Text = ((frmCareer)this.ActiveMdiChild).CharacterName;
                    //}

                    tabMain.SelectedTab = tp;

                    this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag = tp;
                    this.ActiveMdiChild.FormClosed += ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed;
                }

                // Don't show the tab control if there is only one window open.
                if (tabMain.TabCount <= 1)
                    tabMain.Visible = false;
                else
                    tabMain.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        private void ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Form).FormClosed -= ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed;
            (sender as Form).Dispose();
            ((sender as Form).Tag as TabPage).Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
            // Don't show the tab control if there is only one window open.
            if (tabMain.TabCount <= 1)
                tabMain.Visible = false;
        }
        private void tabMain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tabMain.SelectedTab != null && tabMain.SelectedTab.Tag != null)
                (tabMain.SelectedTab.Tag as Form).Select();
        }

        private void closeAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Form childForm in MdiChildren)
            {
                childForm.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**frmCharacter**

```
namespace DarkHeresyCC
{
    public partial class frmCharacter : Form
    {
        private Character _objCharacter;
        public frmCharacter(Character objCharacter)
        {
            _objCharacter = objCharacter;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put here ComboBox fill code

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you're asking for?